# How to apply custom CSS style on SVG <use> element

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-selectors

I am working with an svg element

```js
var defsElement = document.querySelector('defs');
var defsElementX = defsElement.getBBox().x;
var defsElementY = defsElement.getBBox().y;

var colX = [];


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (i == 0) ? colX.push(25): colX.push(colX[i - 1] + 60)
};
//console.log(colX);

const y = 145;

const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

colX.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        let useEl = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'use');
        useEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', "xlink:href", "#stick man");
        useEl.setAttribute("class", "use" + [i]);
        useEl.setAttribute("id", "id" + [i]);
        useEl.setAttribute("x", `${a}`);
        useEl.setAttribute("y", `${y}`);
        svg.appendChild(useEl);
    }
)
```

```css
.stickman {
    stroke: red;
    fill: none;
}

.stickman>.head {
    fill: black;
    stroke: blue;
}

.head {
    fill: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <svg id="layer" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>

            <g id="stick man" style="fill: none; stroke: black;">
            <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
            <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"/>
            <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"/>
            <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"/>
            </g>
            </defs>

            <g class="stickman" id="stickman" transform = "translate (85,50)">
                <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
                <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"/>
                <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"/>
                <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"/>
    
    <script href="index.js"></script>

    
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to learn how to apply CSS styles to different `<use></use>` element. For example, how can I apply 3 different colors for `fill` for each of the `head`. What CSS selector should I use?

I tried like

```
.use0>.head {
    fill: brown;
}
```

It did not do anything.

The `javascript` is generating this

[image: S1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS variables for this:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  let useEl = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'use');
  useEl.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', "xlink:href", "#stickRef");
  useEl.setAttribute("id", `id${i}`);
  useEl.setAttribute("x", (i * 60) + 25);
  useEl.setAttribute("y", 25);
  svg.appendChild(useEl);
}
```

```css
#id0 { --head-colour: #F00; --line-colour: #900; }
#id1 { --head-colour: #0F0; --line-colour: #090; }
#id2 { --head-colour: #00F; --line-colour: #009; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="stickRef" style="fill: none; stroke: var(--line-colour);">
      <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="fill: var(--head-colour)" />
      <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"/>
      <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"/>
      <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome js compatible answer. It works. However, I realized that working with `defs` creates performance burden and the js can't access the svg shadow-dom getting generated with `use`.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap in a group `<g>` with `style="fill: none;"` only the line and polylines of the stick man, leaving the circle with an unspecified fill.

Now you can set a fill attribute or give a style to the `<use>` element. The fill will be applied only to the circle.

```css
use{fill:red}
use:nth-of-type(2){fill:gold}
use:nth-of-type(3){fill:blue}
```

```html
<svg id="layer" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 100 500 500">
  <defs>
    <g id="stickman" style="stroke: black;">
      <circle class="head" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"></circle>
      <g style="fill: none;">
      <line class="body" x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="44"></line>
      <polyline class="upper" points="1 58, 10 44, 19 58"></polyline>
      <polyline class="lower" points="1 24, 10 30, 19 24"></polyline>
      </g>
    </g>
  </defs>


  <use xlink:href="#stickman" x="25" y="145"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#stickman" x="85" y="145"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#stickman" x="145" y="145"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example there's no `use0` class so obviously is not changing anything and your rule:

```
.head {
    fill: brown;
}
```

is just overwritten by:

```
.stickman>.head {
    fill: black;
}
```

Be sure you have a priority css rule to overwritte another rule... there's many ways for it avoiding, if possible, the `!Important` like, for example:

```
body .stickman .head  {
    fill: brown;
}
```

a bit more info about css priorities [here](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/css/precedence.html#:%7E:text=Thus%2C%20if%20two%20CSS%20rules,declared%20in%20the%20second%20rule.)

Comment: `javascript` is generating the `use` element with `use0` class as you can see. How can I ask CSS to grab that? I am not questioning why the color for the top most shape is getting overwritten. I am asking what CSS selector to use to access the bottom 3?

Comment: If your html is generated by javascript then your css rule: `.use0>.head` is being overwritten somehow. Use chrome inspector and you will see what the problem is. Probably adding '!important' would solved it but it's never good praxis.

Comment: '!important'  has no impact.